# MiniZinc -- can someone please fix my code?

Tags: modeling, minizinc

I try to create a work management system. Overall, I try to develop a daily movement strategy, during which the car would end up in the last place at the beginning of the day and collect the people in this row at the end of the day.

Types of work:

- 1 suitable (full day)
- 2 suitable (a full day and a half day)

Restrictions:

- All work should be done
- A specified person is required for job types
- Not exceeding the daily labor limit
- additional necessary constraints

Aim of optimization:

- Minimizing fuel costs

My code:

```
int: num_jobs = 10;
array[1..num_jobs] of int: jobs = 1..num_jobs;
array[1..7] of int: days = 1..7;
int: full_day_workers = 2;
int: half_day_workers = 1;
int: daily_labor_limit = 8;
int: fuel_rate = 10; % Fuel rate in units per distance

% Define the time between jobs as a two-dimensional array
array[jobs, jobs] of int: time = 
[
    [0, 4, 6, 4, 7, 0, 8, 2, 3, 5],
    [4, 0, 3, 7, 2, 0, 6, 8, 1, 5],
    [6, 3, 0, 8, 0, 0, 3, 5, 9, 2],
    [4, 7, 8, 0, 4, 0, 5, 3, 6, 7],
    [7, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 5, 3, 9],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [8, 6, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0, 6, 4, 8],
    [2, 8, 5, 3, 5, 0, 6, 0, 9, 1],
    [3, 1, 9, 6, 3, 0, 4, 9, 0, 2],
    [5, 5, 2, 7, 9, 0, 8, 1, 2, 0]
];

% Define the flattened time and distances arrays
array[jobs * jobs] of int: flat_time = [time[i,j] | i,j in jobs];
array[jobs * jobs] of int: distances = [flat_time[(i-1)*num_jobs + (j-1)] | i,j in jobs];

% Variables
array[jobs, days] of var 0..1: job_schedule;
array[jobs] of var days: end_day;
array[days] of var jobs: starting_job;

% Define job types
set of int: job_types = {1, 2};

% Full-day and half-day jobs
array[jobs] of bool: full_day_job = [if j = 1 \/ j = 3 \/ j = 5 \/ j = 7 \/ j = 9 \/ j = 10 \/ j = 8 then true else false endif | j in jobs];
array[jobs] of bool: half_day_job = [if j = 2 \/ j = 4 \/ j = 6 then true else false endif | j in jobs];

% Constraints
% All work should be done
constraint forall(j in jobs) (
    sum(d in days) (job_schedule[j,d]) = 1
);

% Not exceeding the daily labor limit
constraint forall(d in days) (
    sum(j in jobs) (
        job_schedule[j,d] * (if full_day_job[j] then full_day_workers elseif half_day_job[j] then half_day_workers else 0 endif)
    ) <= daily_labor_limit
);

% A specified person is required for job types
constraint forall(d in days) (
    sum(j in jobs) (
        job_schedule[j,d] * (if j = 1 then full_day_workers elseif j = 2 then half_day_workers else 0 endif)
    ) >= full_day_workers
);

% The car should end up in the last place at the beginning of the day
constraint forall(d in days) (
    starting_job[d] = if d = 1 then 1 else end_day[d-1] + 1 endif
);

% Each job should end within the day it started
constraint forall(j in jobs, d in days) (
    end_day[d] >= starting_job[d] /\
    end_day[d] <= starting_job[d] + sum(d2 in days where d2 > d) (sum(j2 in jobs) (job_schedule[j2, d2] * flat_time[(j-1)*num_jobs + (j2-1)] + fuel_rate * distances[(j-1)*num_jobs + (j2-1)]))
);

% Optimize total distance traveled
var int: total_distance = sum(j in jobs, d in days where d < 7) (fuel_rate * distances[(j-1)*num_jobs + (starting_job[d]-1)]);

solve minimize total_distance;

output [
    "Starting job: ", show(starting_job), "\n",
    "End day: ", show(end_day), "\n",
    "Job schedule: ", show(job_schedule), "\n",
    "Total distance: ", show(total_distance)
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have several syntax issues so the model cannot be run. Here are some of the issues:

- the `jobs` domain should be a set of ints (or enums), e.g. `set of int: jobs = 1..num_jobs;`
- The 2d array `time` should be defined using `array2d`:

```
array[jobs, jobs] of int: time = array2d(jobs,jobs,
[
    0, 4, 6, 4, 7, 0, 8, 2, 3, 5,
    4, 0, 3, 7, 2, 0, 6, 8, 1, 5,
    % ....
    5, 5, 2, 7, 9, 0, 8, 1, 2, 0
 ]);
```

- The two flattened array cannot be defined using the domains `jobs*jobs`. Rather it should be `1..num_jobs*num_jobs`. You can use `array1d(time)` to flatten a matrix, if you need that. However, I'm not sure that you really need these two flattening variables since in MiniZinc you can use the 2d matrix directly in the  constraints. (This flattening might be needed in constraint systems that does not supports the matrix element constraints.)